# Build automation: Is it usual to use QMake for non-Qt projects?

Tags: c++, cmake

So, I'm planning to write a C++ library and I want it to be cross-platform, and as this library won't deal with UI and I want it to have as little dependencies as possible, I won't be using Qt (actually Qt won't really help me to achieve what I want, all I plan on using is STL and Boost). Now when it comes to build a cross-platform project, I really like QMake as it's extremely easy to use and I have experience with it.
I also heard good things about CMake, though I really doubt it's as easy to use as QMake.

Anyway, here is my question: Should I stick with build automation tool that I know or is QMake just out of context for a non-Qt project? Should I take this as an opportunity to learn CMake? Or is there a better alternative to these two?

Comment: Definitely not seeing what this question has to do with C, at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That choice is entirely up to you.

But I will point out that a *very* large number of Qt-based projects have moved away from QMake and switched to CMake, for various reasons. I will also point out that there is no technical reason that you can't use QMake if you prefer it.

Personally, I use CMake, because it quite well takes the role that autotools was once preferred for, doing so with a set of tools and a syntax that's far easier to understand and work in. But I see the appeal of using QMake - the syntax is much simpler and may perhaps be easier to understand and use than CMake.

Comment: Hell, you could use Ant if you felt like.

Comment: I've decided to give CMake a try and while it's definitely n not as easy as QMake it's not nearly as difficult as I thought it would be and it seems pretty powerful too.

Answer (score 2):

I used to work for a company ([Interactive Network Technologies](http://www.int.com)) that created SDKs for use in Contouring, Seismic, Welllog, and GIS space.  The C++ product was supported for multiple varieties of Unix, and Windows (back when you had to define NT versus other flavors)

When QT came out, it already had QMake; I was familiar with make and Ant at the time.  AFter spending three days with QMake, I threw it out and simply used make.

Although make can be brainmeltingly complicated, I'd suggest using it or Ant versus QMake.

Comment: Why? It's clear that you don't like QMake, but why? I think your reasoning would be valuable to understand.

Comment: If I could remember, greyfade, I would tell you.  That was about 8 years ago :-(

Comment: In that case, I submit that it's worth a revisit. :)

Comment: Perhaps, but I've moved away from multiple platforms in my career.  I now develop and distribute Microsoft technologies.